# on keyup event is not working on easyui

Tags: jquery

I have this html

`<input name="telefone" id="telefone" class="f1 easyui-textbox" data-options="required:true" />`

And this js code:

```
$('#telefone').textbox({
        onChange:function(v){
                var r = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
                r = r.replace(/^0/,"");
                if (r.length > 11) {
                    // 11+ digits. Format as 5+4.
                    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)(\d{4})(\d{4}).*/,"($1)$2.$3-$4");
                }
                else if (r.length > 6) {
                    // 6..10 digits. Format as 4+4
                    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4}).*/,"($1)$2.$3-$4");
                }
                else if (r.length >= 3) {
                    // 3..5 digits. Add (0XX..)
                    r = r.replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)(\d{0,5})/,"($1)$2.$3");
                }
                else {
                    // 0..2 digits. Just add (0XX
                    r = r.replace(/^(\d*)/, "($1");
                }

                if (r != v) {
                    $('#telefone').textbox('setText',r);
                }
            }
    });
```

This is working very well but onChange is working like onblur I would like it working like an onkeyup. So I tried this:

`$("#telefone").keyup(function() { alert("ok"); });`

and this

`$("#telefone").on("keyup",function(){ alert('ok'); });`

Got no success =/

Someone, please!!?!?!?

Comment: Why not use `keypress`?

Comment: the problem is, none of them works: keypress,keyup,keydown

Comment: @aldrin27  Actually, this works but not in my context, I'm using this code inside a panel and I guess this is why it don't works, but as I said onChange: works properly even inside the panel.

Answer (score -1):

This work for me:

```
$('#Razon').textbox({
  inputEvents:$.extend({},$.fn.textbox.defaults.inputEvents,{
    keypress:function(e){
      return soloLetras(e);
    }
  })
})
```